# Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ a matrix. Show that $\mathscr{N}(A^TA) = \mathscr{N}(A)$, where $\mathscr{N}(M)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ a matrix. Show that
> $\mathscr{N}(A^TA) = \mathscr{N}(A)$, where $\mathscr{N}(A)$ is the
> null space of the matrix $A$.

Showing that if $x \in \mathscr{N}(A)$ then $x \in \mathscr{N}(A^TA)$ is very straightforward. I'm struggling to show that $\mathscr{N}(A^TA) \subseteq \mathscr{N}(A)$. I could do some algebraic manipulation but it wasn't sufficient:

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & \dots & a_{mn} \\
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \ ; \dots ; \ b_{n} \end{pmatrix}.$

$A^TA=\begin{pmatrix} b_{1}^T \\ \vdots \\ b_{n}^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \ ; \dots ; \ b_{n} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b_{1}^Tb_{1} & \dots & b_{1}^Tb_{n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_{n}^Tb_{1} & \dots & b_{n}^Tb_{n}\end{pmatrix}$

So we have $A^TAx = \begin{pmatrix} x_{1}b_{1}^Tb_{1} + \dots + x_{n}b_{1}^Tb_{n} \\
\vdots \\ x_{1}b_{n}^Tb_{1} + \dots + x_{n}b_{n}^Tb_{n}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

From here I have no idea how to show this makes $Ax=0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without huge computation by assuming general matrix A you can use following steps.

Let,$x \in N(A^tA)$ then,
$A^tAx=0$
$x^tA^tAx=0$

$(Ax)^t(Ax)=0$

Let,$Ax=b$
then, $b^tb$=0

$b$ is real vector in $R^n$

So, b=0 & hence, $Ax=0$
which implies $x \in N(A)$

Comment: It was a duplicate (and mentioned before you anwered, I think).